# How many additional images a product has assigned in Magento 2 - SQL query

Tags: sql, magento

I am creating a query that allows me to see, through a sql query, how many additional photos (additional_images) each product has in Magento 2. But something is not working.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_additional_image_labels, product.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity AS product
JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS media_value ON media_value.value_id = product.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS gallery ON gallery.value_id = media_value.value_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS additional_image_labels ON additional_image_labels.value_id = gallery.value_id
WHERE additional_image_labels.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'additional_image_labels' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
GROUP BY product.entity_id;
```

Comment: let me guess to the count is too high? please explain your probolem

Comment: I need to count how many additional photos each product has. The final report would be, 2 columns, SKU, Number of additional images.

Comment: with out data and tables, we basically lcan't tell what you already got, and what you get with your current and why you want 2. We can't determine what additional images are. before making a question in sql you really should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query